# Lambda VpcConfig in AWS Serverless Application Model

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, aws-sam

I run a handful of Lambda in a private routable subnet and deploy them with SAM:

```
Globals:
  Function:
    Runtime: python3.11
    VpcConfig:
        SecurityGroupIds:
          - sg-085912345678492fb
        SubnetIds:
          - subnet-071f712345678e7c8
          - subnet-07fd123456788a036
```

as per https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-lambda-function-vpcconfig.html#aws-properties-lambda-function-vpcconfig--examples.

This requires that I manually configure the security group and the subnets externally. Is it possible to include the configuration of the security group and the subnets in the SAM file?

Comment: I believe this answers your question https://stackoverflow.com/a/68155484/13070